# jQuery Accessing Widget Attributes

Tags: jquery, widget

Is it possible, to access a widget's attributes in jQuery, like in Dojo?

```
dijit.byId('#controlDiv').attr('text');
```

Comment: Mario, the argument to dijit.byId() would be an id name not a CSS query (and would return the widget abstraction rather than a DOM node)  It's an important distinction because Dojo also has an attr() method on DOM query results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this

```
jQuery('#controlDiv').attr('text');
```

For more details [check this](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what i mean. Is it possible to query an "attribute/property" from an widget. For example, i create a widget on a div using this:
$('#targetdiv').mywidget({text: 'xyz'});
and now, i would get the information what text was provided
$('#targetdiv').attr()
only returns the html attributes...

Comment: i Guess you are trying to insert some text in a div then use this $('#targetdiv').html('xyz');
$('#targetdiv').html();

Comment: note that Dijit uses JavaScript objects to represent widgets behind the DOM, and _Widget.attr() (deprecated in favor of get, set and watch methods) is a convention to access public properties on those widgets.  This is not to be confused with dojo.byId(...).attr() which would be equivalent to the jQuery method here.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what widget you are using - whether it has some accessor methods, or whether the values are in the public scope. What widget are you using?

Comment: Thanks, bute thats not what i mean. Is it possible to query an "attribute/property" from an widget. For example, i create a widget on a div using this:
$('#targetdiv').mywidget({text: 'xyz'});
and now, i would get the information what text was provided
$('#targetdiv').attr()
only returns the html attributes...

Comment: i Guess you are trying to insert some text in a div then use this $('#targetdiv').html('xyz');
$('#targetdiv').html();